# Kotlin Kafka consumer

Tags: kotlin, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to kotlin and kafka. I am trying to read message from a kafka consumer and then process it later in kotlin.
**I am able to print the message consumed from kafka topic.**
However, I am not able to add this message into a list and process it later.

**How to add the message from kafka topic to a list to be processed later?**

Below is my kafka consumer's consume method.

KafkaConsumer.kt

```kotlin
fun consume(handler: (value: String) -> Unit) = thread(start = true) {
        keepGoing = true
        
        consumer.use { consumer ->
            while (keepGoing) {
                consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500))?.forEach {
                    println(it?.value() ?: "no value")
                    handler(it?.value() ?: "empty_message")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am invoking the consume() as shown below

```
fun main(){
<read config>
val kafkaConsumer = KafkaConsumer(config.get(<topicname>))
kafkaConsumer.consume {
        println(it)
}
}
```

PS: I tried to append the to a mutable list in the main() which did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"? Could you please post the code you tried and explain how it behaved and what you expected instead?

Comment: Parts of the code were hidden due to bad formatting, which made it hard to understand your question. Please be careful and re-read your own question after posting to ensure all elements are there next time.

Comment: About your question, how did you try to use the list? Was it concurrent with `consume()`? Did you give `consume()` a chance to add elements before you looked into the list's contents? Did you stop `consume` to stop adding elements before you looked?

Comment: I tried to save the message into list like this: 
var messages: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
kafkaConsumer.consume{value -> messages.add(value)}
Is this right approach to save message into a list?

Comment: That means you'll have shared mutable state with another thread, and you're not using a thread-safe collection, so this is a bad idea. The solution really depends on what you're trying to do conceptually. How do you determine the end of the list? Consume can run forever, so you need to decide when to start/stop it, or you need some stream representation instead of a list, like `Flow`. But it's hard to tell without knowing what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a formatting issue or your actual code, but Kotlin lambdas are defined by `{ }` and you call `consume()` with 2 pairs of braces:

```kotlin
kafkaConsumer.consume { it -> {
        println(it)
} }
```

This is effectively passing a function that takes one argument and returns a function. That returned function takes itself an argument and prints it.
This should not even compile given the signature of `consume()`.

What you probably want is this instead:

```kotlin
kafkaConsumer.consume { it ->
    println(it)
}
```

Note that `it` is also the implicit argument of lambda expressions, so you don't even need to specify it at all:

```kotlin
kafkaConsumer.consume {
    println(it)
}
```